# Subscript numbers

Tags: support, formatting

How do we format subscript and superscript numbers?

For example, I've referred to SO2 a few times, and someone has already edited an answer of mine and converted the '2' to subscript.

Comment: Related: http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/25/mathjax-request

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there's a Markdown way to do it, but Stackexchange allows you to just use the HTML `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags.

So,

```
CO<sub>2</sub> and mv<sup>2</sup>
```

give

CO<sub>2</sub> and mv<sup>2</sup> respectively.

Comment: thanks (9 chars )

Comment: Just to note, there is no markdown support for subscripts and superscripts.